# How can i update my website when i post a message in my discord server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can i update my website when i post a message in my discord server? I would like to know how to collect the messages in javascript because im using discord.py so its difficult

Havent tried anyything yet

Answer (score 0):

You could use an api managed by the discord.py code that updates the data on each message send and access it in js on the client side?

Python api:
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-api-tutorial/

Js accessing the api:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Discord.js which might make this easier, you could also use express for the api
https://discord.js.org/#/

https://expressjs.com/

Also if you want it to dynamically update, try using websockets or something similar to tell the client to re fetch the data or directly send the data to the client.